# OneToMany + JoinTable + OrderColumn: Order is written correctly but not read

Tags: eclipselink, spring-data-jpa, join

I have an entity that can consist of itself:

```
class Group {
    // ...
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinTable(
        name = "group_group",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "parentgroup_id")
    )
    @OrderColumn
    private List<Group> groups = new ArrayList<Group>();

    @ManyToOne
    private Group parentGroup;

    public List<Group> getGroups() {
        return groups;
    }

    public Group getGroup() {
        return parentGroup;
    }
}
```

I can create a group and add two child groups:

```
Group parent = new Group();
Group child1 = new Group();
Group child2 = new Group();

parent.getGroups().add(child1);
parent.getGroups().add(child2);

parent = groupRepository.save(parent);

// parent.getGroups().get(0).getId() == child1.getId()
// parent.getGroups().get(1).getId() == child2.getId()
```

But this seems to be a coincidence. I am able to update the order (e.g. using Collections.sort) and the join table rows are updated correctly.

It does not matter how I load the parent group, the child groups are always in the order of creation. The executed SQL query is:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.PARENTGROUP_ID FROM GROUP t0, GROUP t1 WHERE ((t1.PARENTGROUP_ID = ?) AND (t0.ID = t1.PARENTGROUP_ID))
```

There is no ORDER BY which seems wrong. How can I persuade EclipseLink to add it?

Comment: the SQL statement you've shown isn't for the "group_group" join table you have defined for your OneToMany mapping using the OrderColumn.  It is lazy by default, so try accessing the groups relationship and show the SQL that is generated.  Please note that ordering on collections only occurs when the collection is read from the DB.  Once the entity is cached, you must maintain the ordering in the application or force a refresh on the parent entity to have the collection reloaded from the DB.

Comment: It's the only SQL statement that appears in my log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I tried to load the child group entities using a CrudRepository. The repository ignores the `@OrderColumn` annotation. I fixed it by fetching the parent group and using `getGroups()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `@OrderBy` which does not rely on the database.  You will need to provide a field from `Group` to order by (note **field** not column).

```
@OrderBy("fieldNameGoesHere DESC")
private List<Group> groups = new ArrayList<Group>();
```

`OrderColumn` will maintain the order of the list within the database, which carries additional performance and maintenance overhead.  `OrderBy` puts the onus on the persistence provider to maintain the order of the entities, however the order will not persist across persistence contexts.

For more information, checkout this [blog post](https://tothought.cloudfoundry.com/post/13) I created regarding @OrderBy.